# Is it true that $n^r(X_n-X)\xrightarrow{d}Z$ implies $X_n\xrightarrow{d}X$?

Tags: probability

I see that without this last requirement $n^r(X_n-X)$ would blow up in probability, how to prove this formally? By contradiction maybe? Like assuming it doesn't converge in probability and hence finding a subsequence such that $\mathbb{P}(|X_n-X|>\varepsilon)>\Delta$ for all $k$, and then showing that this implies $n^r(X_n-X)$ to go to infinity in probability?

Comment: What happened to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2974774/36150) of yours? Seems that they are kind of related, aren't they? Moreover, I have the impression that you are confusing "convergence in probability" and "convergence in distribution"...

Answer (score 0):

It's overkill, but it follows trivially from the [Skorokhod representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skorokhod%27s_representation_theorem).  Otherwise you can use a uniform integrability argument to show the characteristic function of $X_n$ converges to that of $X$, where the uniformity comes from the uniform tightness implied by your convergence in distribution to $Z$.

Answer (score 0):

It is true for $r\gt 0$, but not necessarily for $r\gt 0$. Indeed, for each positive $\varepsilon$, 
$$
\Pr\{\left\lvert X_n-X\right\rvert \gt \varepsilon\}=\Pr\{n^r\left\lvert X_n-X\right\rvert \gt n^r\varepsilon\}.
$$
A real number $R$ which is a continuity point of the cumulative distribution function (c.d.f.) of $Z$. Then for all $n$ such that $n^r\varepsilon\geqslant R$, the following inequality holds:
$$
\Pr\{\left\lvert X_n-X\right\rvert \gt \varepsilon\} \leqslant \Pr\{n^r\left\lvert X_n-X\right\rvert \gt R\}
$$
and using the convergence in distribution of $n^r\left\lvert X_n-X\right\rvert$ to $Z$ combined with the fact that $R$ is a continuity point of the c.d.f. of $Z$, we derive that for each $R$ being a continuity point of the c.d.f. of $Z$, 
$$
\limsup_{n\to +\infty}\Pr\{\left\lvert X_n-X\right\rvert \gt \varepsilon\} \leqslant \Pr\{Z \gt R\}.
$$
As $R$ can be chosen as large as wished, we deduce that $X_n\to X$ in probability. Since [convergence in probability implies weak convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236955/convergence-in-probability-implies-convergence-in-distribution), we are done.